# How do I eliminate the spaces?

Tags: scrapy

I would like to collect the Japanese articles searched by google. I try to extract Japanese sentences, then I run the following code in order to get the tag including the most Japanese words.

```
texts = mostTag.xpath('<<path>>/text()').extract()
text = ''
for s in texts:
    text += s
```

but when I run this code, extracted sentence has spaces in their head.
For example, If html is as below and path is '//p',

```
<p class dir='sample'>
    <span>
        <a role='button' tabindex='0' style='white-space: normal;'>A
        B</a>
        <span> </span>
    </span>
</p>
```

I got the sentences as below.

```
             A
B
```

I tried to eliminate this spaces by method 'text.strip()', but the spaces remained.

How do I get the 'AB' from this html? Or how do I eliminate the spaces? I appreciate it if anyone tell me how to get 'AB'.

Comment: you can try using [`text.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '')`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm). It remove every tabs and newline of your string (can add `.replace(' ', '')` if you want to remove space too).

Not doing as an answer since I'm not doing Python so maybe this won't work or maybe there is a better way (which I hope this one way too long for this much)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\n\s+', '', s)
'AB'
```